# Calling class method's method's ... n layers deep

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, repeat

I'm trying to do something equivalent to

```
a=[[[[[1,2,3,4,5]]]]]
res = a.pop().pop().pop()
```

which would return `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`, but I want to be able to do the pop sequence `n` times, so something like
`a.pop() for _ in range(n)` wouldn't work as its calling pop() on the `a` object and not the `a.pop()` object

Any clue on how this can be done in python, and if so what it would be called for future reference? The closest thing I could find is the * operator to convert a list() into separate arguments

I do not want to do something like this(ignoring edge cases):

```
tmp=a.pop()
for _ in range(n-1):
    tmp=tmp.pop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a for loop. What would be acceptable to use?

Comment: You could define a function that contains the loop, then you don't have to write the loop every time.

Comment: I cant do it in a for loop, because the project I'm working on its actually part of a very nested for loop itself. The control flow is kinda weird, but it prevents me from restructuring the entire projects flow. Essentially instead of .pop() its a different method where the arguments change each iteration ex  .filter(changing_Value)

Comment: That makes no sense. You can have nested loops, you don't need to restructure anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is interesting, but I would not suggest you to do what I write below, because it will be unreadable.

First you don't want to explicitly create a function. You want to have a list comprehension like expression to do this. This is the rule.

So how can I do nested function? In math, it is called function composition (i.e., `f(g(h(x))` for functions `f(x)`, `g(x)`, `h(x)`). The only thing that I can think of close enough to this in Python is `reduce`. You can reduce a list of functions into a single "reduced" function. My solution is this:

```
import functools
a=[[[[[1,2,3,4,5]]]]]
five = functools.reduce(
           lambda f,g: lambda x: f(g(x)),
           [lambda x: x.pop() for _ in range(5)],
           lambda x:x
       )(a)
```

You will get `five == 5` above. Which pops the last element from the innermost list.

Let me explain the above a bit:

- `functools.reduce()` is to create a function `f(f(f(f(f(a)))))` which `f(x)` is defined as `x.pop()`. It is nested five times, so I use `range(5)` in the 2nd argument of `functools.reduce()`
- The first argument is to do nesting
- The third argument is to create a function that returns to itself. The idea is for the innermost `f(a)`, we need to express it as a nested function. So it is `f(g(a))` which `g(a)=a` and `f(a)=a.pop()`
- What this whole thing returns is a callable object. So we call it with argument `a` to execute it
- Essentially, this is equivalent to running `a.pop().pop().pop().pop().pop()` with the `a` accessed through an identity lambda function `lambda x: x`

Yes, complicated, and hard to read. But it can be done in Python.

Comment: This is more of what I was looking for. I'm just kinda shocked that python doesn't have a shorthand for something like this. I can understand some issues with the shorthand concept. Mainly the fact that it would need to know the functor that it is pointed to

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursion. this function takes a list and the number of pops you want to perform and returns the result

```
a = [[[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]]]

def pop_n(l, n):
    item = l.pop()
    if n < 2:
        return item
    else:
        return pop_n(item, n-1)

res = pop_n(a, 3)
print(res)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```